# 500 error when querying workfront api Hours + parameterValues

Tags: c#, json, api, attask, workfront-api

When calling WorkFront's API

`https://preview.workfront.com/attask/api/v7.0/HOUR/search?fields=*,parameterValues`

I get a 500 error. It works fine if I don't specify `parameterValues`. In comparison providing a bogus field returns:

`https://preview.workfront.com/attask/api/v7.0/HOUR/search?&fields=*,garbageParam`

```
{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"APIModel V7_0 does not support field garbageParam (Hour)"}}
```

I can't simply remove `parameterValues` because the url is generated by the code, and I didn't see a means of determining if a particular `ObjCode` will or won't crash if given `parameterValues`.

My code is supposed to dump the JSON into C# classes I have, so I need all the fields that are available. Unfortunately WorkFront crashing by being requested all the fields is throwing a wrench into the design.

Is there a way to get around the 500 error, or a way to detect if `paramterValues` should be provided or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are getting a 500 Error rather then a more specific error but Hours do not contain custom data so parameterValues would not contain any data on the HOUR object. If you were to make the same Call on the TASK object it would work.